# Проект в Android Studio выдает кучу ошибок

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk, ide

Уже 4 минуты пытается что то проиндексировать. Вот ряд ошибок, последняя просто повторяется десятки раз. Windows предупреждал что кое-что пропадет и, судя по всему, это часть *gradle*. Как решить?

> <sub>13:46:56 RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: writePrevChunkAddress:98078387,98086429,C:\Users\1.AndroidStudio2.1\system\index\trigram.index\Trigram.Index.values</sub>

> <sub>13:47:01 RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: writePrevChunkAddress:2330935,2352735,C:\Users\1.AndroidStudio2.1\system\index\filenameindex\FilenameIndex.values</sub>

> <sub>13:47:17 Gradle sync started</sub>

> <sub>13:47:19 Gradle sync failed: C:\Users\1.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\settings_8kfxdbmd31mcq7saiba9roeqi\cp_settings\cache.properties (Не удается найти указанный файл)
>            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)</sub>

> <sub>13:47:33 RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: writePrevChunkAddress:2331280,2350625,C:\Users\1.AndroidStudio2.1\system\index\filenameindex\FilenameIndex.values</sub>

> <sub>13:47:34 RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: writePrevChunkAddress:2331767,2350625,C:\Users\1.AndroidStudio2.1\system\index\filenameindex\FilenameIndex.values</sub>

> <sub>com.intellij.diagnostic.MessagePool$TooManyErrorsException: Too many IDE fatal errors. Monitoring stopped.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

У вас повторяется отсутствие файла ресурса values, вот путь:

> C:\Users\1.AndroidStudio2.1\system\index\filenameindex\FilenameIndex.values

Так же отсутствует папка properties по пути:

> C:\Users\1.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\settings_8kfxdbmd31mcq7saiba9roeqi\cp_settings\cache.properties

Gradle не может найти эти файлы для сборки, насколько я понимаю. Если есть бэкап проекта, возьмите оттуда эти файлы.

Так-же не будет лишним переустановка IDE.